# Boolean indexing in Cython

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, indexing, cython

I am new to Cython and trying to Cythonize one of my functions:

```
PerHit %Time    Line
================================
            def lap(grid, ghosts_bool, D, dt):
88.3    14.9    grid_out = np.copy(grid)
72.3    12.2    grid_out *= -6
3.3     0.6     shore = grid[1:, :, :]
1.5     0.3     wave = grid[:-1, :, :]
69.6    11.8    shore[ghosts_bool[1:, :, :]] = wave[ghosts_bool[1:, :, :]]
94.8    16.0    grid_out[:-1, :, :] += grid[1:, :, :]
10.4    1.8     grid_out[-1, :, :] += grid[-1, :, :]
37.1    6.3     grid[ghosts_bool] = 0
2.3     0.4     shore = grid[:-1, :, :]
1.4     0.2     wave = grid[1:, :, :]
68.3    11.6    shore[ghosts_bool[:-1, :, :]] = wave[ghosts_bool[:-1, :, :]]
93.6    15.8    grid_out[1:, :, :] += grid[:-1, :, :]
10.5    1.8     grid_out[0, :, :] += grid[0, :, :]
36.6    6.2     grid[ghosts_bool] = 0
```

It is already optimised in a Numpy manner, but still remains a bottleneck in my program, because with the growth of number of `True` cells in `ghosts_bool` operations with `shore`&`waves` become pretty heavy.

I have got around how to predefine types, send MemoryViews to the function and do boolean indexing in Cython, but bumped into that Cython is not fully supporting in-place operations. `grid_out *= -6` just needs an ellipsis `grid_out[...] *= -6`, but this one does not work and throws an error: `grid_out[1:, :, :] += grid[:-1, :, :]`.

How can I best implement this operation? Or looping is the only option?

Comment: If you aren't doing looping there is little to be gained through Cython. Numpy already implements these operations in fairly efficient C. (The advantage of looping is that you can often avoid creating intermediate values)

Comment: @DavidW I thought through defining types and direct access to the memory view I could gain some
Could you suggest were to look into for further optimisation possibility? I have learned about DASK and Spark and that they allow to split arrays and work on them in multiple threads